# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lingvo==0.11.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

While installing `lingvo==0.11.0` using the command

```bash
pip3 install lingvo==0.11.0
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lingvo==0.11.0 (from versions: 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.3, 0.12.4, 0.12.5, 0.12.6)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lingvo==0.11.0
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Per that packages PyPI package, v0.11.0 requires Python >=3.7, <3.10

Comment: @Brian I'm using 3.10.6. It's also compatible with 3.10, right?

Comment: No, `<3.10` means up-to but not including Python 3.10. You'll need to either upgrade to a version of lingvo that supports Python 3.10, downgrade to Python 3.9, or create your own distribution package for lingvo that allows Python 3.10, assuming that the source is available and the license permits doing so.

Comment: Oh I see.. Where were you able to check for this?

Comment: You can visit the distribution's [index page](https://pypi.org/project/lingvo/), click "Release History", pick "v0.11.0", and then inspect the "Meta" section in the left hand column. If the distribution doesn't provide good metadata, you can also go under "Download files" to seen what Python versions they have provided wheels for, or if source archives are available.

Comment: Good new is, the most recent release (v0.12.6) supports Python >=3.8, <3.11

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you so much! Also, do you know what steps I can follow to downgrade python to 3.9 on ubuntu in WSL?

Comment: You may be able to find a question on that here on SO, or perhaps on one of the Linux-focused sister sites like Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux, or SuperUser. You can try always `apt install python3.9` if you're using a Debian based WSL, but newer releases may not provide Python 3.9 packages anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[You stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75550473/error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-lingvo-0-11-0#comment133294234_75550473) you are using Python 3.10.

However, lingvo 0.11.0 requires "Python >=3.7, <3.10". See the metadata in the sidebar [here](https://%20https://pypi.org/project/lingvo/0.11.0/).

To solve your problem, you have 2 options at your disposal:

- Use an older version of Python (among 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9)
- Use a newer version of lingvo. For example, [lingvo 0.12.1](https://pypi.org/project/lingvo/0.12.1/) requires "Python >=3.8, <3.11"